# The index 2 is out of range

Tags: java, jdbc

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = Connectionstring().prepareStatement(
            "Select Username from dbo.LoginDetails where Username = ? and Password =?");
  String User = tf_Fname.getText();
  String _Pass = new String(tf_Lname.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, User);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, _Pass);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) 
        {
            System.out.println("Username is "+ resultSet.getString(1)+"Password is "+resultSet.getString(2));  
        }
```

Without

```
+"Password is "+resultSet.getString(2)
```

it works fine, it is printing username from the database
but with that it also throws an error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range.
```

Comment: aren't you just selecting the Username? How could there be two things if you are selecting only one item from the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select Username from .....................
```

You have only one column in `select` clause.

Change it to something like

```
  Select Username, yourpasswordcolumnname from......
```

Answer (score 7):

You are only retrieving one column from the table:

```
"Select Username from dbo.LoginDetails where Username = ? and Password =?");
```

Try this:

```
 "Select Username, Password from dbo.LoginDetails where Username = ? and Password =?");
```

Then your code should work, on another related note, NEVER store passwords as "clear text", always use a one way encryption method, and use a salt!

Related: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: ok I have to do it when creating a new user and retrive it here when selecting username,password....I think I am now understanding a bit.Let's see if it works :)

Comment: Don't ecrypt passwords, hash them (with pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt or something similar)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you're totally right, correcting this: When a user first gets sing up into your application hash the password with an irreversible hash, and store the "hashed" password only, then, each time the user logs in, hash the password he is using, retrieve the stored "hashed" password from the database and compare them, if they are the same, let her/him in!

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from dbo.LoginDetails where Username = ? and Password =?
```

will get you the information you need so that you are selecting all columns from `dbo.LoginDetails` instead of just one column, `Username`, like you are right now